# Transistor Based LED Switching Circuit Design

Tags: transistors

I was going over a schematic for a component I was using, and it uses a transistor to switch on an LED. For the most part the schematic makes sense, however I'm not quite clear on the necessity of the cap going from collector to ground. Could anyone provide some insight into this?

[image]

The component in question is for Sparkfun's  AT42QT1010 breakout. Here is the full schematic to perhaps add some further context.

[image]

Comment: A link to the schematic please.

Comment: Soft turn-on turn-off, perhaps? Won't be visible with 10 nF to the naked eye but maybe the author was building something sensitive to 20 mA current steps on power rail?

Answer (score 1):

200R * 10 nF = 2us  reduces the radiated noise on a cable for the SW band somewhat if it was nearby the radio on a weak channel.  f=0.35/tR is the -3dB point. For 10~90% thus T ~3us.

Otherwise it is not needed.

In most cases your CMOS 50 Ohm driver can drive the Green LED directly with same or a resized Rs value. The ARM driver is closer to 25 Ohms. With cathode to 0V or Anode to Vdd.

EDIT 2:20pm.
The added schematic imposes no requirement for the LED cap.

So it was probably added for “insurance” (lack of analysis) of pop noise reduction on AM/SW radio interference. Considering the low current and low inductance of cable, it is useless otherwise.  However poor wiring might cause some crosstalk.

Answer (score 0):

It provides a little extra surge of current through the transistor each time it turns on. Otherwise, it makes no sense.

If the capacitor had been connected to the node between the resistor and the LED, it could be argued that it would help keep some of the noise of switching the LED on and off out of the power supply.

Comment: "It provides a little extra surge of current through the transistor each time it turns on." That is what I was thinking, but I can't see the motivation for it... I will update my question to include the specific component and full schematic, perhaps it can clarify things more.